# Giving file location from parent of the parent folder in C++

Tags: c++, qt, file

I'm a newbie to C++ and I know its a basic question but couldnt find a satisfactory answer from anywhere so I'll read the file location from parent folder but I dont know how.

Executed file is in

**C:\A\B\C\D\Test.exe**

The file I need to open is in

**C:\A\E\F\Open.exe**

But I want to do this dynamically. So config of the text.exe should give a path to A then into E and F. Because this program can be located anywhere and I dont want to give a path starting from C:\

Any help would be appriciated. I'm using QT too if it helps. Thanks

***EDIT :***

I am looking for something like

```
<a href="../../other/file.pdf">file.pdf</a>
```

in html

***EDIT 2:***
This is my code but its not working

```
QSettings setting("config.ini",QSettings::IniFormat);
QString prolocation = setting.value("ProDir","../../../E/F/pro.exe").toString();

QProcess process;
process.start(prolocation);
```

And config file is:

(bla bla other settings)

ProDir=../../../E/F/pro.exe

Comment: Is the directory `C:\A` fixed, will it never change?

Comment: Its not fixed, it will definetely change, thats the question

Comment: You can use [QSetting](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) as configuration for your path.

Comment: Okay, then will `A` always be in the root of `C:`? Then just create a string containing `"C:/"` and append the directories as needed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it wont always be on C: it can even be on USB

Comment: @Simon I know about the QSetting but I want my path to be dynamic you know how can I say in a string file path that it should go 3 folders up and then into e and into f and find open.exe

Comment: Last question: Will the (configurable) path always be absolute from the root directory of whichever drive it's located on? Then there's really no different from my previous comment, just create a string starting with the drive letter and continue appending directories.

Comment: Only absolute path is starting from A to D and A to F. Before that can change

Comment: If what you want is to iterate the folders you can use [QDiriterator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdiriterator.html#details)

Comment: @Simon I've edited the question and added an example of what I want, if it helps

Comment: In windows you can use PathRemoveFileSpec and PathStripPath API's to get the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also can use [QUrl::resolved](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qurl.html#resolved)

> Calling resolved() with ".." returns a QUrl whose directory is one level higher than the original. Similarly, calling resolved() with "../.." removes two levels from the path. If relative is "/", the path becomes "/".

```
QUrl oBase("file:///home/A/B/");
QString oResolvedFile = oBase.resolved(QUrl("../../other/file.pdf")).toString();

// Test 
QFile oLocalFile(QUrl(oResolvedFile).toLocalFile());
if (oLocalFile.exists())
{
    // your file
}
```

Comment: I gave the file location like "../../other/file.pdf" in a config file. t gets it right but doesnt open the process. I use Qstring qwe = setting.value("blabla","../../other/file.pdf").toString();

I dont have a QUrl base because it may change how can I use resolved in this way

Comment: @SamedSivaslıoğlu You get the correct file path, but failed to open it? Can you share your code to see what is actually not working? :)

Comment: who is going to change the base URL? from config? by user? if user changed it you can get it from [QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory)

Comment: I put my code to the question. Btw thanks for all your help @Simon you're great:D

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working Qt solution

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDir>
#include <cassert>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Init + get app path
  //
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

  QString appPath = app.applicationDirPath();
  qInfo() << appPath;

  // App path manips
  //
  QDir dir(appPath);

  // Goes up two times... your C\D dirs
  bool ok;
  ok = dir.cdUp();
  assert(ok);
  ok = dir.cdUp();
  assert(ok);

  qInfo() << dir.path();

  // Goes to picaud/Temp again
  // -> in your case /E/F dirs
  ok = dir.cd("picaud");
  assert(ok);
  ok = dir.cd("Temp");
  assert(ok);

  qInfo() << dir.path();
}
```

which prints:

```
"/home/picaud/Temp"
"/home"
"/home/picaud/Temp"
```

In your case, like you already use Qt I think this is the simplest approach. You can still use the C++ standard [filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) but this requires either to use C++17 or to use the  [Boost initial implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).